# Spring Security OAuth2 get Access Denied on REST Service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to secure my Spring REST Services with Spring security and OAuth2. I managed to get the tokens:

[tokens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRzVR.png)

But when I try to get an secured rest service I get access denied:

[denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRZxH.png)

Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

AuthorizationServerConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static String REALM="EXAMPLE_REALM";

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler handler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("myRestClient") // client id
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .secret("{noop}P@ssw0rd")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(240).//invalid after 4 minutes.
            refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);//refresh after 10 minutes.
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(handler)
                .authenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.realm(REALM+"/client");
    }

}
```

ResourceServerConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer

public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "SPRING_REST_API";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
        anonymous().disable()
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**")
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{        
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles("USER")
            .and()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
                .roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/about").authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore){
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

}
```

AboutController (rest service):

```
    @RestController
public class AboutController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/about", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> home() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("This is a demo application to show how to secure REST API using Spring Security and OAuth2", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At a glance:  your in-memory auth defines `ROLE_CLIENT` but your endpoint is looking for `ROLE_ADMIN`.

Comment: Alternative take:  what happens if you place in an `Authorization` header the token as a bearer? So that'd look like `Authorization:  Bearer <UUID>`.  It seems awkward and potentially *broken* to pass the token in as a query parameter in your URL so that should ideally not need to be there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got this working.** My problem was that in the application.config file I added /api so that for all my services an api folder is in place like: http://localhost:8080/**api**/about .. in my ResourceServerConfig class I added /api/** as requestMatchers and antMatchers.... the sercurity configuration is looking for serverice after this api prefix folder.... so exposing my about rest is done in this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "SPRING_REST_API";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
        anonymous().disable()
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/about/**")
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/about/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

By the way.. I can request the about service with a parameter like in my request screenshot but it works also if i provide the authorization token als a Bearer Token authorization header....

Regards!

Peter